# What are covectors in special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, vectors, covariance

In special relativity the purpose of vectors makes fairly intuitive sense, they represent a point in spacetime:

$$x^{\mu}=\begin{pmatrix}x^0 \\ x^1 \\ x^2 \\ x^3\end{pmatrix}$$

and we can define the spacetime interval with the metric tensor:

$$d\tau^2\equiv\eta_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}$$

which means that $\eta_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}$ is a covector and that:

$$d\tau^2\equiv dx_\nu dx^\nu$$

where

$$x_\nu=(x^0, -x^1, -x^2, -x^3)$$

my question is what does this covector represent physically and what is the difference between vectors and covectors in special relativity? If a vector represents a point in spacetime does a covector also represent a point in spacetime?

Comment: https://www.naturelovesmath.com/en/mathematics/about-numbers-episode-5-tensors/

Comment: The line element is differential $2-$form - it is not a tensor. When $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}$ is the vector, $dx^{i}$ is the co-vector, such that $\langle dx^{i},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\rangle=\delta^{i}_{j}$ - they must both be at the same space-time point - the vector in the tangent space and co-vector in the cotangent or dual space.

Comment: Don’t think of 4-vectors as representing points in spacetime. This doesn't work in curved spacetimes. You should think of them as living at a point in spacetime (more technically, in the tangent space at that point) and indicating a direction in spacetime away from that point.

Comment: My advice is to treat $dx^\mu$ as intuitive and $dx_\mu$ as formalism. On the other hand, treat $\partial_\mu$ as intuitive and $\partial^\mu$ as formalism.